# json string to php to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json

Here's my json String i get:

```
[data] => {"id":"0612833398","longitude":"-143.406417","latitude":"32.785834","timestamp":"10-10 07:56"}
```

And i need it to put it like this in my php file, but i only get NULL values.

```
<?php
file_put_contents('dump.txt', "POST: \n" . print_r($_POST, true) . "\n\n\n GET: \n" . print_r($_GET, true));

$link = mysql_connect('server', 'bla', 'bla')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('md267052db227433') or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$id = $data['id'];
$latitude = $data['latitude'];
$longitude = $data['longitude'];
$timestamp = $data['timestamp'];

}
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($id), mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),  mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp))  ;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
echo "OK";


// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

I Feel like im really close:
The dump.txt from line 1 looks like this:

POST: 
Array
(
)

```
 GET: 
Array
(
    [data] => {"id":"0612833398","longitude":"-143.406417","latitude":"32.785834","timestamp":"10-10 07:56"}
)
```

Comment: Where are you getting null values?

Comment: use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` as you are getting `data` in GET

Comment: I get this in my database. All Null values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transform into array, and change to `$_GET`:

```
if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_GET['data'], true);
    $id = $data['id'];
    $latitude = $data['latitude'];
    $longitude = $data['longitude'];
    $timestamp = $data['timestamp'];

    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO locatie (id, longitude, latitude, timestamp) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($id), mysql_real_escape_string($longitude),  mysql_real_escape_string($latitude), mysql_real_escape_string($timestamp))  ;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
    echo "OK";

    // Free resultset
    mysql_free_result($result);
}
```

If the second argument of `json_decode` is true the function will return an associative array instead of object.

As a side note, if you started to build your project it's best to move your code to MySQLi or PDO because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and should no longer be used. [Check this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) nice tutorial to get you started.

Comment: AWESOME, only thing is... I get 2 values in my database.. 2 times the same values

Comment: print the Query to see what it is trying to do ...

Answer (score 2):

That json is Object serialization not an array
You should write:

```
$data = json_decode($_GET['data']);
$id = $data->id;
$latitude = $data->latitude;
$longitude = $data->longitude;
$timestamp = $data->timestamp;

}
```